Is there a way to compile a .NET 8 project to run on Windows 8?
I am new to .NET development environment. I have created a project with .NET 8. It works perfectly on Windows 10+, but the problem happened when I run it on Windows 8. It wouldn't load.
I looked around the internet and found out that the latest support of .NET for Windows 8 is .NET 5. Is there a solution for this case? Or should I change my project to target .NET 5?
I've tried this but there are too many syntax difference from .NET 8 to .NET 5. Is there a better solution?

"Is there a solution for this case?" - No, because why on earth would anyone still be running Windows 8 today?

Windows 8.1 is coming up on two years being unsupported.  Is it really worth the time?

If you really need such an old OS, you might consider using the good old .net framework 4.8. I believe it will be better than net5 because of the support policy (net FW is still receiving security and compatibility fixes, and net5 - not). And no, you can run the modern versions of .net on Win8.

Upgrade the Operating System
Advocate for upgrading the operating system to Windows 10 or later. Since Windows 8 has reached the end of its lifecycle, it's not only unsupported by modern .NET versions but also poses security risks.
